# NGINX Alias domain redirect to HTTPS main domain

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two domain names:

domain1.com - Main domain with SSL

domain2.com - alias of the domain1.com

For domain1.com I have purchased SSL certificate and installed it properly and it works fine. Now I want to redirect traffic from domain2.com to domain1.com (SSL), but the issue is that I am keep getting error: "Connection not private".

How can I redirect domain2.com alias domain in nginx to main domain with ssl without the above error?

Comment: redirect from non-ssl `http://domain2.com` or SSL `https://domain2.com`

Comment: redirect from non-ssl http://domain2.com to SSL https://domain1.com